# cakePHP creating custom id's for checkboxes

Tags: cakephp

I have a checkbox list that I create using the form helper

```
echo $form->input('Interest.interest_id', array('label' => __l('Interests'), 'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

It then created for each checkbox and automatic id

eg.

```
<input id="InterestInterestId1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="data[Interest][interest_id][]">
<input id="InterestInterestId2" type="checkbox" value="2" name="data[Interest][interest_id][]">
```

Is it possible to have my own unique id that I create for each checkbox? For example customInterestInterestId1, customInterestInterestId2 ...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
echo $form->input('Interest.interest_id', 
                            array('label' => __l('Interests'),
                                 'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                 'id'=>'your_custom_id_')); // add ID to the array
```

It works for the other auto-magic input types; but I haven't tested it with a multiple check box.

Cake will then generate:

```
... id="your_custom_id_1" ...
... id="your_custom_id_2" ...
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but this is not working, it changes the id of the label to the given one,<label for="interests_">Interests</label>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="data[Interest][interest_id]">
<div class="checkbox">
<input id="InterestInterestId8" type="checkbox" value="8" name="data[Interest][interest_id][]">